# Emulate low physical memory in Visual Studio

Tags: debugging, memory, visual-studio-2015

I am attempting to debug a performance problem that a customer is experiencing by reproducing it in-house. We suspect that the problem is that the customer has a small amount of physical RAM and the program is paging to disk. This is causing very slow reports.

Is there a way to get Visual Studio to emulate this behaviour when I debug? I would like to closely reproduce in house what I have seen at the customer so that I am sure that I am actually fixing the relevant problem.

---

<sub>Using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 (14.0.24720.00 Update1) 

with ReSharper Ultimate 2015.2 (103.0.20150818.200216)</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest creating a Virtual Machine for this, you will then be able to specify exactly the amount of memory/CPU that the machine is to have.  The OS will see this as physical limits, so you will be able to tweak it up and down easily without having to build/reinstall any OS (but would need to restart VM most likely).

For this kind of thing I use the free version of VMware Player, which will happily build a VM from install media.

HTH

Comment: Sounds workable in the absence of a Visual Studio debug option, I'll give it a go...